# Boundary operator: what does it mean?

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplex, simplicial-complex

I'm getting some confusion in simplicial homology...Take a very simple example, a (solid) tetrahedron:

[image]

Following the well known property that "the bounday of a boundary is zero", we would end up with $\partial\partial=0$.

Instead, using the "chain complex" concept, the boundary operator seems to map the solid tetrahedron to the "void tetrahedron", and the latter to its edges.

So it seems to me that "taking the boundary" has at leat two different meanings...where am I wrong?

Comment: You should assume the tetrahedron and each faces, edges are *directed*, and use $\pm$ signs according to the directions.. For example, take the solid triangle $ABC$, then it's boundary is $AB+BC+CA$. The boundary of $XY$ segment is $Y-X$. So we'll get for the double boundary $B-A\, +\, C-B\, +\, A-C\ =\ 0$.

Comment: You're obvioulsy right, but the matter is still unclear to me...I'll say it differently: when we operate the "first" boundary on $ABC$ we get, as you say, $AB+BC+CA$. Then we do the "second" boundary and get $0$. But if this is the mechanism, _every_ $k$-simplex will be $0$, because in fact it's the boundary of another boundary...

Comment: No, e.g. the 1-cell $AB$ itself is not zero, it's not a boundary of any 2-cell

Comment: I see...so, reassuming, are $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C_k @>\partial>> C_{k-1}\ @>\partial>> C_{k-2}\
\end{CD} and $$\partial\partial(C_k)$$ in fact the same operation?

Comment: There's a notational contradiction in your last comment, and perhaps it is not really what you wanted to ask. This object $$C_x \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{k-1} \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{k-1}$$ is a sequence of two homomorphisms, whereas  the object $$\partial\partial(C_k)$$ is a subgroup of the chain group $C_{k-1}$, in fact it is the trivial subgroup. It is accurate to say that the subgroup \partial\partial(C_k)$ is the image of that composition. However, it is not accurate to say that those two objects are "the same operation": a sequence of two homomorphisms is not a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @LeeMosher...in fact my question is fairly simpler: does the double $\partial$ operator, in the simple case of tetrahedron, map to $0$, or (as some books say) map to the space of $k-2$-dimensional collections of simplices?

Answer (score 3):

In Homology, we *formally* add and subtract *directed* simplices.

0-simplices are the vertices. They have boundary $0$ by definition.
1-simplices are directed segments, so that $BA=-AB$. $\ \partial(AB) =B-A$. 
The $n$-simplex $A_1\dots A_n$ is considered to be the same as $A_{\sigma(1)}\dots A_{\sigma(n)}$ if $\sigma$ is an even permutation, and its negative if $\sigma$ is odd.
Define $\partial(A_1\dots A_n) =(A_2\dots A_n)\, - \, (A_1A_3\dots A_n) \, +\, \dots\,\pm\, (A_1\dots A_{n-1})$.
(the $i$th term omits $A_i$, with alternate signs)

---

Now, in particular for the $ABCD$ simplex, we get
$$\partial(ABCD)=BCD - ACD + ABD - ABC\\
\partial(XYZ)=YZ+ZX+XY\\
\partial(\partial(ABCD)) = BC+CD+DB\ - \ AC-CD-DA\ +\ AB+BD+DA\ -\ AB-BC-CA\ =\ 0$$

Comment: I deeply thank you to your effort and your straightforward answer. It is clear why algebraically $\partial\partial$ maps $ABCD$ to $0$...So why some books (e.g. Bobenko-Schroder, _Discrete differential geometry_) say that the $\partial$ operator map the tetrahedron _"[..]to its triangles, **then** to their edges, **then** to their vertices"_? Does $\partial\partial$ map the tetrahedron to $0$ or to the space of collections of edges?

Comment: If we don't introduce alternate sum in the definition (which corresponds to forgetting about directedness), then we don't get $\partial\partial=0$ (unless we take all coefficients only modulo 2). It's also possible not to insist on the Abelian group structure, and consider the boundary e.g. simply as a subcomplex.. Then the statement $\partial\partial=0$ doesn't even make sense..

Answer (score -1):

Simply because when you take one of these triangle and you apply once again the boundary operator you obtain the (oriented) segments of the triangle.
To put it "simply" the boundary operator decompose a figure into pieces that compose him.

The accuracy of my answer is maybe not too high, because I also begin in the study of such object.