# How to geometrically visualize addition of one forms?

Tags: differential-forms

I am going over the [publicly available pdf](https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Ermont/papers/Burke_DivGradCurl.pdf) of "Div, Grad, curl are dead", in chapter-2 , section-11, the algebra of one forms is introduced  (see page-37). In it, I understood how to take negative of a one form, we just put a tick on the line, and also the scaling features (put the two lines closer) but I can't get how the addition rule is supposed to be.

The author has given the following picture on the page:
[image]

Hopefully someone can give a more elaborate explanation of the icon addition scheme shown above

Answer (score 1):

For an elementary understanding, translate it into vectors, by naming $A,B,C$ the vertices of the triangle:

The first one is

$$\vec{AC}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BC} \iff C-A=(B-A)+(C-B)$$

The second one is

$$\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=0 \iff (B-A)+(C-B)+(A-C)=0$$

which are clearly equivalent.

Remark: the second notation in (1) and (2) comes from a more abstract point of view, necessitating to consider homology chains, with boundary operator $\partial$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284326).

Comment: Wait what relation between vectors and one forms did you use to turn the one form addition in vector addition?

Comment: The correspondence with vectors is through the **homology** "border operator" $\partial$: $\vec{AB}$ identified with $B-A$. Do you follow me ?

Comment: Do you mean the exterior derivative? I think I saw it in later sections of the book but didn't really read through it. But, why would you need that to say that the a vector is formed by difference of points?

Comment: This point of view is rather common. It is **the way an affine space is built from a vector space** by selecting a point $Z$ as origin, and transforming equality $\vec{AB}=\vec{ZB}-\vec{ZA}$ into $\vec{AB}=B-A$ (by identification of "vector" $\vec{ZX}$ with "point" $X$.

Comment: Fine, so far I've got that you corresponded points in space w/ position vector to that point, but how does the boundary operator fit in here?

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284326) where you will see $\partial AB=B-A$ homological notation.

Comment: That's a lot of notation I am unfamiliar with, I'll return to this after reading more on the terms discussed in that post (soon^tm). However, thank you for the answer :)