# Understanding the statement "the boundary of the boundary of a simplex is zero"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplex

Suppose that we have a triangle simplex $S=(p_{1}p_{2}p_{3})$, then the boundary of $S$ $\partial S$ is defined by $\partial S=p_{1}p_{2}+p_{2}p_{3}+p_{3}p_{1}$, then $\partial \partial S=p_{1}-p_{2}+p_{2}-p_{3}+p_{3}-p_{1}=0$,but from wikipidea, the plus sign here is not the sum of vectors or sum of sets, it is used to separate each member in the set and the set consists of finite k-simplexes, so my questions are:(1) what is the meaning of $0$ here(2) why the sum is $0$, as to the second question I think $p$ and $-p$ cancel out but I don't know how to understand the above sum $p_{1}-p_{2}+p_{2}-p_{3}+p_{3}-p_{1}=0$ rigorously

Comment: Replace zero by the empty set.

Comment: It is a formal sum belonging to the free abelian group on the set of vertices: to every vertex $p$ you associate a symbol, also denoted $p$. The free abelian group on the vertices is the set of finite sums of these symbols (e.g. $0,p_1+p_2,2p_3-7p_1$ etc).

Comment: @Douglas: It should be a free module over $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the vertices, not a free abelian group.

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3284489/305862 (obtained using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: I vote to reopen. The question is not about $\partial^2=0$ but about understanding the nature of chains, their summation and zero.

Comment: @freakish just so you know, the OP agreed with the duplicate vote - that's what the appearance of the "Community" user shows in the close dialog (mouse over the community user's profile link to see the explanation in alt text).

Comment: @YoungMath A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is the same thing as an abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about boundary operator, then you already have to have chains introduced. Given a simplicial complex $\Delta$, and a ring $R$ we define $C_n$ to be the free module over $R$ with (oriented) $n$-simplexes of $\Delta$ as basis. Elements of $C_n$ are called $n$-chains and are formal sums of $n$-simplexes with formal coefficients taken from $R$. When $R$ is a field then this means vector space, when $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then this means free abelian group.

Either way $C_n$ is an abelian group at least. And thus all rules of the abelian groups apply to it.

So what is a chain? We are not dealing with Euclidean vectors here or some set unions. We are dealing with an abstract construction that follows certain rules. So for example if $A,B$ are two $n$-simplexes then we can form their sum $A+B$. And that's it. That's their sum. It is not another $n$-simplex, it is a formal sum, an expression of the form $A+B$. It is w chain. We can also multiply $n$-simplex by say $5$ (given $R=\mathbb{Z}$). Then we get $5A$. That's it. It is not a simplex $5$ times bigger than $A$, no, it is an expression of the form $5A$. Finally since we deal with an abelian group then it also has a zero. Again, you may think of it as some abstract expression, lets use $\Theta$ symbol to represent it (so that it resembles standard zero, but also says clearly that it is some abstract thing).

Those formal expressions are not without rules. Since we deal with abelian groups, then we have $A+\Theta=A$ for any $n$-simplex $A$. We also have $A+B=B+A$. Furthermore $A-B$ is not a reducible expression, unless $B=A$, in which case $A-A=\Theta$, just like in any group.

> I think $p$ and $-p$ cancel out but I don't know how to understand the above sum $p_{1}-p_{2}+p_{2}-p_{3}+p_{3}-p_{1}=0$ rigorously

Yes, they cancel out: $p-p=\Theta$. Expressions you wrote follow the standard rules of any abelian group. There's nothing more to that.